# Chane child state from parent in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I just started learning React and I have a couple cards I want to toggle a className from the component and remove the className from Parent. How do I do this? This is the child component

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState} from 'react'

const Card = ({check,cardID}) => {
const [isToggled,setToggle] = useState(false)


const flip = () => {
  setToggle(!isToggled)
  check()
}


return (
 <div className='flip-card' >
    <div id={`card${cardID}`}  onClick={flip} className={`flip-card-inner ${isToggled ? "flipclass":""}`}>
    <div className="flip-card-front">
        <span>Flip for surprise</span>
    </div>
    <div className="flip-card-back">
        <img className="card-img" src="/firstsect.jpg" alt="Avatar" height="100%" width="100%" />
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
)}

export default Card
```

and in the parent component I want to set the isToggled state to false so the flipclass wont be added

```
import React from 'react'
import Card from './Card'
import { useState, useRef } from 'react'

export const Cards = ({cardsarray,cardID}) => {
const [Counter,setCounter] = useState(0)



const check = ()=> {
    setCounter(count => count+ 1)
    
    if (Counter === 1) {
        //Change isToggled on the other component to false
        setCounter(0)
    }
}

return (
<div className="all-cards">
    {
      cardsarray.map((_user,index)=>(
        <Card cardID={index} check={check} key={index}></Card>
      ))
    }
</div>
)}
```

I already tried using the state in the parent component and passing the istoggled as props but the whole array of cards gets the class instead of the particular card that calls the function. How do i go about this?

Comment: So an individual card can be flipped on click. On which condition do you want this to be reset?

Comment: If the counter state is 1

Comment: @digitalbreed I am incrementing the counter from the other component and i would want to reset it when the counter gets to 1

Comment: The counter handling isn't working as you would expect; you would need to implement an effect to reset it after a change because the `Counter` value wouldn't have changed right after `setCounter`. I've created a small example, does that do what you expect? https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-ully-7qq4vx?file=/src/App.js